# facing problem in placing Angular Material toast in the left top of the browser using MatSnackBar

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I am working on Angular material toast using MatSnackBar ,

- I wanted to place Angular toast on the **left** & **top** of the
  browser
- but I am facing **problem** as this.snackBar.open() , receive only **3
  argument**

> - when I am adding 4th argument config , for the placement of the toast    , and thus I am facing problem

```
 code : 

     toster(){
       let message = 'you don't have Internet connection' ;
       let action = 'please try again';
        let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();

        config.horizontalPosition = 'right';
        config.verticalPosition = 'top';


        this.snackBar.open(message, action ,{duration: 4000 } , config);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the duration property into the config option like this

```
toster(){
   let message = "you don't have Internet connection" ;
   let action = 'please try again';
    let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();

    config.horizontalPosition = 'right';
    config.verticalPosition = 'top';
    config.duration = 4000;


    this.snackBar.open(message, action , config);
  }
}
```